# NVDA - Is it possible to narrate something on click of button?

Tags: html, jquery

I have refresh captcha button added role, name, aria-label is working. I want to narrate something by NVDA on clicking the same button. Is it possible by jquery or any other solution for this?

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="createCaptcha()" aria-label="Refresh captcha" role="button" tooltip="Refresh Captcha"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

I have tried to give 'aria-labelledby' but it is not working as expected.